# Getting a weired behavior when windowing an audio signal

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, window-functions

I am processing audio signals using [Essentia](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/), an open-source library and tools for audio and music analysis, description and synthesis.
Here is a waveform corresponding to a frame extracted from an audio signal. The plot is obtained with the following instruction:

```
plt.plot(essentia.array(audio_pool['frames.actual-frames'][22]))
```

[image: original-signal]

... and here is the previous waveform, windowed. The plot is obtained with the conjunction of these two instructions:

```
w = std.Windowing(type='hamming',
                  size=len(audio_pool['frames.actual-frames'][22]),
                  normalized=False)
plt.plot(w(essentia.array(audio_pool['frames.actual-frames'][22])))
```

[image: windowed-signal]

We can see that the resulting waveform is somehow inverted, i.e. the beginning of the original signal occurring in the middle.

I tried other window types (rect, hann, etc.) as well as w/ and w/o zero-padding the original signal, I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the windowing function that is used performs by default ["Zero-Phase Zero-Padding"](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Zero_Phase_Zero_Padding.html) on the input signal.
You can disable this feature by setting the `zeroPhase` parameter to `False` as follows:

```
w = std.windowing(type='hamming',
                  size=len(audio_pool['frames.actual-frames'][22]),
                  normalized=False,
                  zeroPhase=False)
```